# How to Update a Static HTML File

Tags: java, html, xml

I'll generate a XML file from JAVA RCP application. I'll create a static HTML file from JAVA object using FileIO operation. In certain cases I'll update the XML file and same has to be updated in the static HTML file.

Please put in your thoughts how best we can update the HTML file considering the above scenario without hitting the performance even if the HTML file is huge or XML file is huge.